# How can I create a menu that will appear from the corner of the screen when a menu button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

to be clear, I want to add a hamburger menu in an HTML web app that will open a menu screen when clicked. I want the menu to animate from the corner of the screen (where the menu button is located). I would like to accomplish this using HTML, CSS, or javascript because those are the languages I'm currently studying. If someone could recommend a beginner-friendly method to accomplish the above-stated goal, I would be extremely grateful. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried google.com

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @Paul's answer - definitely use Bootstrap, and if you are going to use Bootstrap, don't forget to link the Bootstrap library to your HTML file in your header and reference jquery and javascript near the end of your code. More complete instructions can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using a framework for this project. I would like to figure out a method using vanilla HTML, CSS, and JS.

Comment: You can use jquery which will listen to a certain event and then react accordingly.  So for a dropdown menu, the triggered event is clicking on the button and then the server will respond with a listed menu right below the button.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for an easy way to do it, I would reccomend Bootstrap as it is a great resource and CSS framework for creating lots of components. I suggest looking at its [dropdowns](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/) library for creating a hamburger menu.

Cheers.

Comment: I want to avoid using a framework. Is there a way to accomplish this with vanilla HTML, CSS, and JS?

Comment: @JoshLowy I am sure it is possible to do so, but it would take quite some time. I would do some heavy research on how to make it. But remember that we aren't your personal IT guys.

Comment: Duly noted. Thanks for the help.